# How to browse the document file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Am building an iOS app that requires user uploading pdf files. I want to create a button that after the user clicks it, it opens the file directory to search for the specific file to upload to the server.
I will appreciate if anyone can tell me how to do it using swift.
Thank you

Comment: Am sorry if my question wasn't clear. I wanted finding it if apple has documentation for document directory which someone has pointed out and is what am looking for. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller It has helped. Thank you for pointing out how to go about asking question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can consider:
1. If you have to give permission for sharing document directory in your .plist. Then traverse through file app.
2. Or you have to use UIDocumentBrowserViewController and show list of file and directory.
Please check this link : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.